# Python + Pandas + Spark - How to import a dataframe into Pandas dataframe and convert it into a dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I import a dataframe into Pandas dataframe and convert it into a dictionary?

I have this dataframe created from Spark,

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSQL")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    path = os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], "examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

# Create the DataFrame
df = sqlContext.read.json(path)

# Register this DataFrame as a table.
df.registerTempTable("people")

# SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext
teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people")

sc.stop()
```

When I try to import it into Pandas,

```
teenagers = pd.DataFrame(teenagers, columns=['name'])
```

I get this error,

> [client 127.0.0.1:50885] PandasError: DataFrame constructor not
>   properly called!

After all, I just want to convert the dataframe into a dictionary,

```
dict = teenagers.set_index('name').to_dict()
print dict
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Spark DataFrame can be converted to a pandas DataFrame with the [`toPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) method.